# limit of a function in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: limits, functions

Take $U ={\mathbb{R}^2}\setminus{\{(0,0)\}}$ and consider $f:U\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

> $1.$ Set $V ={\mathbb{R}}\setminus{\{0}\}$ and define $g:V\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ so that $g(x)=f(x,y_0)$ where $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. 
>   Show that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ exists and calculate its value.

---

> $2.$ 
>   Show that $\lim_{p\to (0,0)}f(p)$ doesn't exist.

---

I'd guess that the answer for question $1.$ is $0$ because $\frac{0}{y_0}= 0$.

For question $2.$ I suppose the limit does not exist because you can't divide by $0$ (I don't know how to write it formally).

Comment: Chris.2) take1) x=0; y \rightarrow 0, y \not =0. 2) y=0, x \rightarrow 0, x \not =0. Take limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rigorous way to prove that the limit does not exist is to consider $(x,y)\to 0$ along a fixed direction so on the line $y=x$ we have

$${x^2\over x^2+y^2}={1\over 2}\to {1\over 2}$$

While on the line $y=2x$ we have

$${x^2\over x^2+y^2}={1\over 5}\to {1\over 5}$$

An infinity of different limits according to the direction along which $(x,y)\to 0$

*the point of this exercice is that the existence of limits component wise does not prove the existence of a limit*